# Google Sheets Script: Get/Set a Cell's Formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Are there script functions that will get/set the formula defined in a cell? For example, if the cell formula is `=A3*B3`, that's what I'd like to get &/or set. Similar to the spreadsheet function FORMULATEXT().

I found the function **getDataSourceFormula**, and tried that using:

```
  var dataFormula = sheet.getRange('Chart_GetData').getDataSourceFormula;
```

'*Chart_GetData*' above is a Named Range  - a single cell.  It's formula is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(ROUND(GOOGLEFINANCE(B3,"close",K6,TODAY(),"DAILY"),{0,2}),"offset 1",0))
```

But all it returned (in the Logger) was:

`dataFormula : function () { [native code] }`.

Any suggestions pls?

[Edit] Found another function, **getFormula**, but it returned the same result in the Logger...

Comment: How about those brackets when you call a function? :)

Comment: Du-oh!  This is not the first time I've picked a function from the drop down list and forgotten the parentheses. <sigh>  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My error as pointed out by @Dmitry - forgot the parentheses.

Using the function getFormula **()** did the trick. :)